# ppt vba multiple slide selection macro error

Tags: vba, input, range, powerpoint, selection

When multiple PowerPoint slide numbers are entered in the input box (ex: 3, 5, 6), I want to create a macro that selects the slides of the entered number, but an error occurs.

```
Sub test()

Dim strresponse2 As String
Dim iresponse2 As String
strresponse2 = InputBox("page number" & vbCr & "ex) 2,4,11,5")

If IsNumeric(strresponse2) Then
iresponse2 = strresponse2
End If

ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect
ActivePresentation.slides.Range(Array(iresponse2)).Select
'error here
'How to fix it so it doesn't get an error

'ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(2, 4, 11,5)).Select
'no error

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to enter something like `2, 4, 5` in the inputbox and expect that slides 2, 4, and 5 are selected?

Comment: yes i want ....

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here.
a) If you enter `2, 4, 5`, the check for `IsNumeric(strresponse2)` will fail because the function tries to convert the whole string into *one* single number.

b) `Array(iresponse2)` will not convert the string into an array (of 3 numbers). It will convert the single string `2, 4, 5` into an string array with 1 (not 3) member.
In your case, you can use the `Split`-function to split the input string into an array of strings.

c) If you want to access the slides by number, the input needs to be of a numeric type, not of string (even if the strings contain numbers). You will need to convert the string array into a numeric array (if you pass a string or an array of strings as parameter, VBA will look for members with the *name*, not the *index*).

Have a look to the following piece of code and check if it does what you need - it's only half tested (as I have no Powerpoint VBA available, only Excel, but the priniple is the same)

```
Dim answer As String
answer = InputBox("page number" & vbCr & "ex) 2,4,11,5")
Dim pagesS() As String

pagesS = Split(answer, ",")                 ' Split the answer into an array of strings.
ReDim pagesN(0 To UBound(pagesS)) As Long   ' Create an empty numeric array
Dim countS As Long, countN As Long 
For countS = 0 To UBound(pagesS)            ' Loop over all strings
    If IsNumeric(pagesS(countS)) Then       ' String is Numeric
        Dim pageNo As Long
        pageNo = Val(pagesS(countS))        ' Convert string to number
        If pageNo > 0 And pageNo <= ActivePresentation.slides.Count Then
            pagesN(countN) = pageNo         ' When number is within valid range, copy it 
            countN = countN + 1             ' Count the number of valid page numbers
        End If
    End If
Next countS

If countN > 0 Then                          ' At least one number found
    ReDim Preserve pagesN(0 To countN - 1)  ' Get rid of unused elements
    ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(pagesN).Select    
End If
```

Comment: Just confirming that your code works well in PowerPoint, even when I deliberately entered alpha characters or numbers > slide count.  Nicely done.